# PHP $this not assigned to a variable

Tags: php, class, oop, variables, methods

I know the basics of PHP OOP but I just noticed something in some code I'm reading online. Please see below:

```
class ControllerCheckoutCart extends Controller {

public function index() {
    $this->load->language('checkout/cart');

    $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

    $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'href' => $this->url->link('common/home'),
        'text' => $this->language->get('text_home')
    );

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'href' => $this->url->link('checkout/cart'),
        'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title')
    );
  } 
}
```

I understand the syntax where the `$this-load-language('checkout/cart');` is collecting the returned information from cart file in the checkout folder, but how is the Index method using this if the `$this` isn't being assigned to a variable? For example, the line `href' => $this->url->link('common/home')` makes perfect sense to me.

The data collected from the common/home file is being assigned to the `href` in the array, which I can then use... But where is the checkout/cart info being stored so the Index method can make use of it?

I tried to Google this but when I Googled 'PHP $this not assigned to variable', I was receiving a lot of unnecessary information.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: I am not completely sure but according to me when you called this index function using class object 
    the function load the checkout/cart language to memory till the function exectuion not ends and since 
    this is available to the current program execution the next line of code will able to get data form it.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Foo {

    protected $bar;

    public function baz() {
        $this->bar = 'baz';
    }

}

class Controller {

    protected $foo;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->foo = new Foo;
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->foo->baz();
    }

}
```

This is what you're seeing. `->load->language(..)` does *something* to the internal state of `load`, or some other object. It doesn't need to have a return value in order to do something useful.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. Is there a way for me to find out which file load() is being called from, so I can look at what being done to it?

Comment: It's probably best to figure out *what `load` is* and then read its class definition and/or documentation. See `var_dump($this->load)` and you should be able to determine its class, then just search for it.